# Update failed: Could not create directory error message

Tags: wordpress, server, cpanel, file-permissions

I tried to update plugin and wordpress it shows an error message. I tried to change file permissions 777. But no use. other sub domain websites have the same issue. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PlWh.png)

Comment: Try adding this to your wp-config.php:  define('FS_METHOD','direct');

Comment: Not working. I tried to add this code in wp-config.

Comment: have you made 777 recursively? it is important if you have decided to solve that via permission change.(correct way is changing flle ownership recursively)